# printer queue stuck with a "unable to find trailer dictionary" error

Tags: printer

I tried to print some PCL files directly to my HP printer and that apparently screwed up the print queue somehow. Rebooting the system does not help. lpstat says:

> printer xyz disabled since ...
>       loadFile failed: temp file: unable to find trailer dictionary while recovering damaged file

How do I solve this problem?